# Where session data Sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to have an sql query, in which the session data `'id'` equals a variable.
Currently I have this query to fetch events from calendar :

```
<?php
// List of events
 $json = array();

 // Query that retrieves events
 $requete = "  SELECT * FROM `evenement` LEFT JOIN `evenementontvanger` ON `evenementontvanger`.`idEvent` = `evenement`.`id` WHERE `idEvent`=`evenement`.`id`";

 // connection to the database
 try {
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blackboks-calendar', 'root', 'root');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
  exit('Unable to connect to database.');
 }
 // Execute the query
 $resultat = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

 // sending the encoded result to success page
 echo json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

?>
```

**And I think the answers should be something like this:**

```
$requete = "  SELECT * FROM `evenement` LEFT JOIN `evenementontvanger` ON `evenementontvanger`.`idEvent` = `evenement`.`id` WHERE `idWerknemer`=`"$this->session_data['id']"`";
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be as

```
$requete = " SELECT * FROM `evenement` 
    LEFT JOIN `evenementontvanger` ON `evenementontvanger`.`idEvent` = `evenement`.`id` 
    WHERE `idWerknemer`='".$this->session_data['id']."'";
```

The string data should be enclosed with single quote '', if its integer you need not provide ''

Comment: Indeed, the character ` is meant to escape field names so that they are not mistaken for something else, in case they match the name of a sql function for example.

Comment: When i do this it doesnt show any events. But i got a row where the idWerknemer=20 and the session data is 20 too. So i dont get why it wont show anything.

Comment: do u have idWerknemer field on both table and if yes then u need to specify evenement.idWerknemer or the other table. Also try executing the query directly on the mysql and see if u get any error

Comment: hmm looking at your first query I suppose u need `WHERE idEvent= `

Comment: Column 'idWerknemer' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: yes u need to specify tablename.column_name in this case.